# Expected value inequality with zero-mean variable

Tags: probability, inequality, self-learning, jensen-inequality

Let $X,Y$ be independent real valued random variables. In addition $\mathbb{E}[Y] = 0$ and $p\geq 1$. 
Then $$
\mathbb{E}[ |X|^p] \leq \mathbb{E}[ |X+Y|^p]
$$
How can I prove this? I tried to use Jensen
$$
\mathbb{E}[ |X+Y|^p] \geq  |\mathbb{E}[X+Y]|^p = |\mathbb{E}[X]|^p
$$
but I don't know how to incorporate independency.

Comment: How did you use Jensen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
E|X+Y|^{p}&=\int_{{\bf{R}}\times{\bf{R}}}|u+v|^{p}d\mu_{(X,Y)}(u,v)\\
&=\int_{{\bf{R}}\times{\bf{R}}}|u+v|^{p}d\mu_{Y}(v)d\mu_{X}(u)\\
&\geq\int_{{\bf{R}}}\left|\int_{{\bf{R}}}vd\mu_{Y}(v)+u\right|^{p}d\mu_{X}(u)\\
&=\int_{{\bf{R}}}\left|E(Y)+u\right|^{p}d\mu_{X}(u)\\
&=\int_{{\bf{R}}}|u|^{p}d\mu_{X}(u)\\
&=E|X|^{p}.
\end{align*}

Comment: This proof also works for not independent random variables? You just have to condition on $X$, right?

Comment: You see, $\mu_{(X,Y)}$ splits into $\mu_{X}\mu_{Y}$, this is what independence meant to be.

Comment: Now I see. I meant this proof $E[|X+Y|^p] = E[E[|X+Y|^p|X] ] \geq E[|X+E[Y|X]|^p] ] =   E[|X+E[Y]|^p] ] = E[|X|^p]$, but it also uses independence. Indeed, it is the same as yours. Thank you